# Static linking C library on Solaris using SunStudio

Tags: c++, c, solaris, solaris-10

I know that in Solaris 10 Sun now Oracle don't provide  static version of C library i.e libC.a 
but I check that same thing is not possible using Sun Studio either, I was under impression that C library are provided by Compiler just like Visual Studio provides C runtime libraries.

So is on Solaris C libray is provided by system only and there is no way to   get static version of libC.a compatible on Solaris 10?
Thanks

Comment: Careful - `libC` is the C++ standard library, `libc` is the C standard library.  Both come with the OS on Solaris, not with the Studio compilers.

Comment: Why do you want a *static* version of a system library, particularly libc? If you use a static library, then you are forever welded to that particular version and your maintenance costs jump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you can find one. This is "by design" - while the stdlib API are stable, the internals change between releases of the OS, so they force everyone to link dynamically to avoid breakages.

Using dynamic version *in theory* keeps your executables portable across different Solaris releases (but it is not guaranteed).

If you really want to have a completely self-contained executable, you probably should use GCC with its own stdlib.

Comment: gcc has not its own stdlib on Solaris.

Comment: Err... I actually meant glibc.

Comment: Which is what I infer you meant. There is no glibc port for Solaris. gcc on this platform uses the bundled libc which is only provided as a shared library for the reasons you state. Your third paragraph describes something that cannot be done, especially from Solaris 10 onward.

Comment: Perhaps was it GNU/kOpenSolaris ? There hasn't been any other glibc port attempts I'm aware of. (http://csclub.uwaterloo.ca/~dtbartle/opensolaris/)